# Swapping External SD Card Memory with Internal Memory on Android Lollipop

Tags: external-sd, 5.1-lollipop, insufficient-memory

I own an Xperia M2 D2303, and I'm on the latest Lollipop build (see footnote).

I've followed [this tutorial](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=46679197#post46679197) but to no success since it'd seem Sony has changed the memory address (previously on Kitkat it was **179:33**). For some reason after entering as per the guide:

```
mount -t vfat -o umask:0000,uid=1000,gid=1023 /dev/block/vold/179:33 /storage/sdcard0
```

it is returning me with this error: 
`No such file or directory`. 
 
I would appreciate for help on the swapping memory.

---

Rooted Sony Xperia M2 D2303 
OS: Android Lollipop 5.1.1 
OS Build: 18.6.A.0.182 
Bootloader, ROM etc.: Stock

Answer (score -1):

try with this

```
sudo mount -t vfat -o umask:0000,uid=1000,gid=1023 /dev/block/vold/179:33 /storage/sdcard0
```

I'm not sure but it may work or it try to find aosp rom mm6

Answer (score -1):

f*ck that thats the solution https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=24421527759890054 u can adopt the external sd and addit to internal one look at that

"You're not missing anything. The option to use SD as internal memory is not included in the Xperia devices. It seems that, because SD transfer rates are significantly slower than internal memory, the performance loss was too great and the option was not included.

Official Sony Xperia Support Staff"

but its work just fine but i dont have google frame and shitz on my device.

Comment: So basically it's flashing a custom ROM? Please rephrase your answer to make it more clearly, and remove your personal rants that are unrelated to OP's question.